# Default Time Out on WooCommerce Recent Products?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

WooCommerce Recent Products shortcode suddenly not working. Is there a time out feature that's doing this?

I'm currently echoing out the recent products using the shortcode.

```
<span class="product-list"><?php echo do_shortcode('[recent_products limit="3" columns="3"]'); ?></span>
```

It worked before, but it suddenly stopped. Is there a timeout feature for recent products? I was on this project a couple of weeks ago, but since I've come back to it, the recent products have disappeared. Am I just doing something wrong, or do products stop showing after a certain time?

Comment: I've tested your exact code on a blank new theme with woocommerce and it's working. Where did you put this code ? Can you try to disable your plugins ?

Comment: That's the thing. I created the site and recent_products portion on my local computer, then pushed it up to the live site. This was working fine. It wasn't until I had to work locally where I brought it down to my local computer again. That's when it stopped displaying. After pushing it back to live, it was showing up again. It might just be an anomaly.